# codeigniter doctrine many to many relationships

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine, many-to-many

I have three tables.

```
User
  id
Group
  id
UserGroup
  user_id
  article_id
  date_joined
```

Now I have three separate models to set up the relationship.

// User Model

```
<?php
class User extends Doctrine_Record
{
    // define table columns in this function
    public function setTableDefinition() {

    }

    // setup some options
    public function setUp() {

        $this->hasMany('Group as Groupss', array(
                'local' => 'user_id',
                'foreign' => 'group_id',
                'refClass' => 'UserGroup'
        ));

        // causes 'created_at' and 'updated_at' fields to be updated automatically
    $this->actAs('Timestampable');
    }
}
```

// Group Model

```
<?php

class Group extends Doctrine_Record
{
    // define table columns in this function
    public function setTableDefinition() {

    }
        $this->hasMany('User as Users', array(
                'local' => 'group_id',
                'foreign' => 'user_id',
                'refClass' => 'UserGroup'
        ));     

    }
}
```

// UserGroups

```
<?php

class UserGroup extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->hasColumn('user_id', 'integer', 4, array(
                'primary' => true
            )
        );

        $this->hasColumn('achievement_id', 'integer', 4, array(
                'primary' => true
            )
        );
        $this->hasColumn('date_completed', 'timestamp', 25);
    }
}
```

and now all i want to do is build the relationship inside my controller:

```
    $user        =      Doctrine::getTable('User')->findOneByEmail('abcd123@gmail.com');
    $group =        Doctrine::getTable('Group')->findOneByID('1');

    $user->Group = $user;
```

Both SQL commands are returning one result and when I run the controller I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Unknown record property / related component "User" on "Group"' in
```

Answer (score -1):

The `refclass` option in the User and Group classes should most likely be UserGroup and not UserGroups (Doctrine doesn't understand the difference between singular and plural). You should also invoke the parent::setUp() method in each of the setup() methods you declare.

There's an extensive amount of documentation on many-many relationships in [the official manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/zh#relationships%3ajoin-table-associations%3amany-to-many). (Which uses the user-group relation as an example)

EDIT:

I noticed some severe problems with the code while going through it again:

- Your `UserGroup` table has an `article_id` column, but no `group_id` column.
- The declared relation to the `Group` model under the name `Groupss`, this making the relation `$user->Group` unknown.
- Finally, you should assign the user to an array of groups like `$user->Groups[] = $group`

Comment: the pluralization of UserGroups was actually a typo on my stackoverflow post (and has been updated). The guide you sent me was the one i was following which is why I'm not sure I'm receiving an error. I notice that in the tutorial they are using 
"class User extends BaseUser" maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: it's also worth noting I added a column to my relational table (date_completed)

Comment: The BaseUser is a class generated by Doctrine that reflects all the information that the YAML configuration contained at the given time. It's simply a matter of code separation, so I can't imagine that this would be the source of the problem. Could you try generating the models in a different directory from the YAML configuration and see what differences are in place?

Comment: i have generated all of my models by hand and did not use YAML to build them